# Calculating the address: pointer + non-negative number

Tags: c, pointers, memory

Pointers can only move in discrete steps.

```
int *p;
p = malloc(sizeof(int)*8);
```

Therefore, formally *(p+2) is calculated as *(p+2*sizeof(int)).

However If I actually code the above two, I get different results, which seems understandable.

```
*p = 123;
*(p+2) = 456;
printf("%d\n",*(p+2*(sizeof(int)))); \\0
printf("%d\n",*(p+2)); \\456
```

The question is, is this calculation implicit, done by the compiler at compile time?

Comment: *is this calculation implicit, done by the compiler at compile time?*: Yes. Exactly.

Comment: In a digital system **every** calculation is done in discrete steps. And "Therefore, formally `(p+2)` is calculated as `(p+2*sizeof(int))`." is wrong. `(p+2)` is calculated as `(int *)((char *)p+2*sizeof(int))`. The dereferentiation is a different operation. You might want to read a good C book.

Comment: The calculation is implicit, done by compiler. In the same way that you index an `int[]` array by 0, 1, 2, 3 (you don't multiply by `sizeof(int)`), the same goes for pointer arithmetic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The question is, is this calculation implicit, done by the compiler at
>   compile time?

Yes this is implicit, when you write `ptr+n` it actually advances forward n times as many bytes as size of pointee type (e.g. in case of `int*` - this is 4 bytes granted integer takes four bytes on your computer).

e.g.

```
int *x = malloc(4 * sizeof(int)); // say x points at 0x1000
x++; // x now points at 0x1004 if size of int is 4
```

You can read more on pointer arithmetic.

Answer (score 1):

> Therefore, formally `*(p+2)` is calculated as `*(p+2*sizeof(int))`.

No, `*(p+2)` is calculated as `*(int*)((char*)p+2*sizeof(int))`.

Even a brief look reveals that the only way for your statement to hold is if `sizeof(int) == 1`.